# BigQuery Node.js API Permission Bug

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

I am building a Node.js server to run queries against BigQuery. For security reasons, I want this server to be read only. For example, if I write a query with `DROP`, `INSERT`, `ALTER`, etc. statement my query should get rejected. However, something like `SELECT * FROM DATASET.TABLE LIMIT 10` should be allowed.

To solve this problem, I decided to use a [service account with "jobUser" level access](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix). According to BQ documentation, that should allow me to run queries, but I shouldn't be able to "modify/delete tables".

So I [created such a service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF9Xo.png) using the Google Cloud Console UI and I pass that file to the BigQuery Client Library (for Node.js) as the `keyFilename` parameter in the code below.

```js
// Get service account key for .env file
require( 'dotenv' ).config()
const BigQuery = require( '@google-cloud/bigquery' );

// Query goes here
const query = `
  SELECT * 
  FROM \`dataset.table0\` 
  LIMIT 10
`

// Creates a client
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: process.env.BQ_PROJECT,
  keyFilename: process.env.BQ_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
});

// Use standard sql
const query_options = {
  query : query,
  useLegacySql : false,
  useQueryCache : false
}

// Run query and log results
bigquery
    .query( query_options )
    .then( console.log )
    .catch( console.log )
```

I then ran the above code against [my test dataset/table in BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zWhs.png). However, running this code results in the following error message (fyi: `exemplary-city-194015` is my projectID for my test account)

```
{ ApiError: Access Denied: Project exemplary-city-194015: The user test-bq-jobuser@exemplary-city-194015.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project exemplary-city-194015.
```

What is strange is that my service account (`test-bq-jobuser@exemplary-city-194015.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) [has the 'Job User' role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZMr9.jpg) and the Job User role [does contain the `bigquery.jobs.create permission`](https://imgur.com/a/RYraK). So that error message doesn't make sense.

In fact, I tested out all possible access control levels (dataViewer, dataEditor, ... , admin) and I get error messages for every role except the "admin" role. So either my service account isn't correctly configured or @google-cloud/bigquery has some bug. I don't want to use a service account with 'admin' level access because that allows me to run `DROP TABLE`-esque queries.

**Solution:**

I created a service account and assigned it [a custom role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW7JI.jpg) with `bigquery.jobs.create` **and** `bigquery.tables.getData` permissions. And that seemed to work. I can run basic `SELECT` queries but `DROP TABLE` and other write operations fail, which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem. To make queries you need both `bigquery.jobs.create` and `bigquery.tables.getData` permissions. The `JobUser` role has the former but not the latter. I created a custom role (and assigned my service account to that custom role) that has both permissions and now it works. I did this using the Google Cloud Console UI `( IAM -> Roles -> +Add )` then `( IAM -> IAM -> <set service account to custom role> )`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows, your service account doesn't have permissions to create **BigQuery Job**

You need to grant it *roles/bigquery.user* or *roles/bigquery.jobUser* access, see [BigQuery Access Control Roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles), as you see in this reference *dataViewer* and *dataEditor* don't have **Create jobs/queries**, but *admin* does, but you don't need that

To do the required roles, you can follow the instructions in [Granting Access to a Service Account for a Resource](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource)

From command line using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding), run

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $BQ_PROJECT \
    --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACOUNT_EMAIL \
    --role roles/bigquery.user
```

Where `BQ_PROJECT` is your project-id and `SERVICE_ACOUNT_EMAIL` is your service-account email/id

Or from [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project) search or add your service-account email/id and give it the required ACLs

Comment: It appears my service account (test-bq-jobuser@exemplary-city-194015.iam.gserviceaccount.com) does have the Job User role. [pic1](https://imgur.com/a/VTq2E) [pic2](https://imgur.com/a/iAxEs)